# why does it not recognise include files and folders

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

everytime i try to compile it to test it doesnt recongnise files

```
#include <GL\glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

#ifdef _WIN32
#pragma comment(lib, "winmm.lib")
#endif // _WIN32

int main(void)
{
    GLFWwindow* window;

    /* Initialize the library */
    if (!glfwInit())
        return -1;

    /* Create a windowed mode window and its OpenGL context */
    window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "Hello World", NULL, NULL);

    if (!window)
    {
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }

    /* Make the window's context current */
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    if(!glewInit())
      return -1;

    /* Loop until the user closes the window */
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        /* Render here */
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        /* Swap front and back buffers */
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);

        /* Poll for and process events */
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesnt recongnise files"? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: yes i put the needed include filess and it doesnt recongnise it

Comment: Look into your pre-compiled headers directory if there is such a file.

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: your question is poorly asked. You need to be more precise in what your asking

Comment: well i try to compile the file so i can test glfw and then it gives me an error

Comment: that #include <GL/glew.h> doesn't exist and #include <GLFW/glfw3.h> doesn't exist

Comment: What are you using to compile? how does your folder structure look. It's clear that you've not told the compiler where it can find the `glew` and `glfw` headers.

Comment: i'm using mingw to compile

Comment: mingw is not really a compiler. I'm assuming your using gcc. Did you passs arguments to gcc for the location of the includes for `glew` and `glfw`

Comment: yes i am using gcc

Comment: Did you supply the include flags??

Comment: and i did not pass arguments to gcc for the location of the includes for glew and glfw because i don't know how to do it beceause my iq is like 90

Comment: Where did you installed `glew` and `glfw`? And in what folder is your code? What is the command used to compile it? Does it tell mingw where to find those files?

Comment: and i did not include flags because i don't know hot becausse again my iq is like 90

Comment: i insstalled glfw and glfw in their websites and my code folder is Src and command is D:\\mingw\\mingw32\\bin\\g++.exe

Comment: Learn the difference of `#include <filename>` and `#include "filename"` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21593/what-is-the-difference-between-include-filename-and-include-filename) Then think again where your files are.

Comment: bruh that doesn't make sense

Answer (score 0):

When you are using a compiler you need to tell it the directory to find files that you include.
In the line

```
#include <GL\glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
```

This is telling the compiler to include the files `glew.h` and `glfw3.h`.
The problem is how is the compiler supposed to know where those files are (it doesn't search your entire Drive for them. c++ compilers have a way for you to tell it where these files are relative to.

In gcc/g++ you use the `-I` flag and specify where this directory is.

specify the folders where you stored `gl\glew.h` and `glfw\glfw3.h`to the gcc using that `-I` option. If your files are store in `C:\Users\John\Projects\dependencies\GLFW\include\glew\glew.h` and `C:\Users\John\Projects\dependencies\Glew\include\glfw\glfw3.h`
then use the the flags like so

```
gcc -IC:\Users\John\Projects\dependencies\GLFW\include
    -IC:\Users\John\Projects\dependencies\Glew\include main.c -o out_file
```